# If the data is sorted What sorting algorithm will Quick Sort turn to be?

Tags: sorting, quicksort

when we have for example array like that 1 2 4 5 6 7 9 11 10 12
needs to be sorted using quick sort, What sorting algorithm will Quick Sort turn to be?

**UPDATE**
I mean that quick sort algorithm in this case will look like[in implementation] to which sorting algorithm

Comment: What do you mean? A quick sorts a quick sort

Comment: I updated the post, hope you got what I mean

Comment: It will still be quick sort, no swaps occur, but the recursive partitioning will be the same. If the middle element is chosen for pivot, then time complexity is O(n log(n)), if the first or last element is chosen for pivot, then time complexity is O(n^2);

Answer (score 2):

Quicksort is a sorting algorithm, not an implementation of a sorting algorithm in a programming language.

The performance of Quicksort on a sorted (increasing or decreasing) array, or nearly-sorted array is O(n^2).

Now, if you are thinking of a programming language's implemention of "sort(...)" were the sorting algorithm is chosen based on number of elements to sort, then it's usually Insertion Sort for a smaller number of elements (n <= k) and Quicksort (n > k).

Wording is important here because an algorithm is independent of any programming language. Wether or not the language can express the semantics (read: meaning) of the algorithm is dependent on the the programming language itself. (And, I guess, the person writing in that language.)

Comment: If the middle element is chosen as the pivot point, then time complexity of Quicksort on a sorted or reverse sorted array will be O(n log(n)).

Comment: @rcgldr You're absolutely correct. I was referring to Nico Lomuto's choice of pivot (in CLRS 3rd edition, section 7.1).